# How to access Snowflake Database from .Net application using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webforms, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am building an ASP.NET application which accesses Snowflake database for getting table data. I have added connection string as below and also added database context class.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SnowflakeContext" 
         connectionString="Offline=False;URL=XXXXXXXXX.snowflakecomputing.com;User=XXXXX;Password=XXXXX;Server=localhost;Database=DEMO_DB;Warehouse=COMPUTE_WH;Account=SYSADMIN;" 
         providerName="System.Data.CData.Snowflake" />
</connectionStrings>
<entityFramework>
    <providers>
        <provider invariantName="System.Data.CData.Snowflake" 
                  type="System.Data.CData.Snowflake.SnowflakeProviderServices, System.Data.CData.Snowflake.Entities.EF6" />
    </providers>
</entityFramework>
```

I want to show the data from snowflake database table on an `.aspx` page using Entity Framework. I tried creating a grid view control and while adding data source I only get SQL Server and I don't get Cdata Snowflake. I have even installed `Snowflake.data` package from NuGet. Can someone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a C# programmer but I think you'll probably need to install the [Snowflake ODBC driver](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/odbc.html) and then connect up the grid view to an ODBC data source (see the second example on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource?view=netframework-4.8)).

Comment: I now get the following error "The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.CData.Snowflake' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details ".                                                                              Can someone please help me out with this exception. I have added the connection string in my config file  but still get that invariant name is not registered.